# Why are we getting continuous unknown indexer errors when reindexing a video?

Tags: indexing, video-subtitles

Trial---95f66ad252---014edac0-d4ba-4844-b91e-5493ff8d99e7

We have been indexing videos without any issue. We are now experiencing problems when reindexing an already indexed video.

We got an error email without

The process is the following:

- We send a video to index and Azure returns it correctly indexed.
- We review the subtitles and the alignment of them with the image and correct it.
- We resend the corrected video to Azure to be reindexed and we get errors on the indexation. This used to work smoothly

We have repeated the process with the same video several times and always got an error. Not always at the same percentage of the process.

We also did the process with other videos but they also didn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't aware that my problem will end here. I don't have much information about the problem. We sent a video to the Azure AI indexer and it works fine. If we reindex it, Azure always raises an error with no more information.